# QProcess::readAllStandardOutput() truncates result

Tags: c++, qt

My Qt program needs to send a command line with a `QProcess` and retrieve the result, which will then be stored in a `QString`.

Here is my code:

## MainWindow.h

```
class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
  Q_OBJECT

private:
  QProcess p;

  void sendCommand(QString command);

private slot:
  void fetchResult();

  // ...
}
```

## MainWindow.cpp

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
  QMainWindow(parent),
  ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
  connect(&p, SIGNAL(readyReadStandardOutput()), this, SLOT(fetchResult()));

  // ... 
}

void MainWindow::fetchResult()
{
  QString result = p.readAllStandardOutput();

  // ...
}

void MainWindow::sendCommand(QString command)
{
  p.start(command);
  p.waitForFinished();
}

// ...
```

I then send commands like this: `sendCommand("cat " + filename);` (for example) and I expect to get the result in the `result` variable located in `fetchResult()`.

Everything works like a charm, but... if the result is too big (~700 chars) , it is trucated. Strange thing: the variable contains the **end** of the string I am expecting.

Where do I miss something.

Comment: You have to read multiple times.

Comment: `p.waitForFinished();` is going to interfere with your signal / slot. You can't receive the signal when waiting.

Comment: I would expect `p.waitForFinished()` to truncate the end of the result, then. The fact that I receive the end and not the beginning implies that it is actually finished when I receive it.

Comment: Try commenting out `p.waitForFinished();` although I expect `fetchResult()` to be called multiple times.

Comment: I placed a `qDebug()` just after the `readAllStandardOutput()` to check what was coming. The `result` variable contains all the text, but in chunks. As my method overrides the content of a `QTextBrowser`, it takes all the text chunk after chunk, leaving only the last chunk displayed. If you place that as an answer, I'll accept it!

Comment: What I don't understand is why it split it up when you used `waitForFinished()`. I would have expected the signal to be received after the process ended because of the wait. I know it does split it up without `waitForFinished()`. I use that method in a few of my medical imaging applications.

Comment: If I remove the `waitForFinished()`, it simply never returns anything.

Comment: That is unexpected / I have not seen that behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you want to wait until the end of the execution, try this, it works for me:

- add `Slot` like `private slots: void cmdFinished();` to receive `QProcess::finished` signal:

```cpp
void MainWindow::cmdFinished()
{
    // process Standard Output result
    fetchResult();

    // process Standard Error result
    //fetchErrResult(); // add it if you want to process Errors (p.readAllStandardError())
}
```

- connect only `QProcess::finished(int)` (remove connection to the signal `readyReadStandardOutput()`):

```cpp
connect( &p, SIGNAL(finished(int)),
         this, SLOT(cmdFinished()) );
```

Hope it helps you.